# Why did Imam Bukhaari consider the hadith on fasting on the day of Arafat expiating 2 years worth of sins to be weak?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, sawm

I've heard that imam Bukhaari did not consider the hadith in sahih Muslim on fasting on the day of Arafat expiating 2 years worth of sins to be authentic. https://www.abuaminaelias.com/fasting-on-day-of-arafat-or-not/
Why was that?